# PDF generator in Javascript - No Plugins

Tags: javascript, pdf

I am trying to create a PDF generator in JavaScript. I know that it will be easy in java but i am just wondering how/if you can create a PDF without using Java or a plug-in? This will make it a lot easier for me to do that's why.

This will be put onto a website for a university project i am doing.

Thanks

Comment: It's certainly possible. You just have to limit the scope of your project to only support the parts of the PDF specification you absolutely need to achieve your goal. However, canvas2PDF gives you that capability.

Comment: Brilliant thank you for the pointer!